# Balancing an AVL tree C++

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I'm implementing a balance function for an AVL tree in C++, and I'm checking for imbalance as follows (it works currently):

```
    if (left > right) {
        if (x->left == NULL || height(x->left->left) > height(x->left->right)) {
          rotateRight();
        } else {
          doubleRotateRight();
        }
      } else {
        // need to rotate left, analagous code as above
    }
```

My question is this: I fully understand the second part of the or statement where I compare heights of x->left->left and x->left->right. The first part is what confuses me. If x is a node of an AVL tree, how can x->left be NULL if the height of the left children of x is greater than the height of the right children of x?

Comment: Are you saying that you know for a fact both those statements are true in your question; are you determining the height correctly?

Comment: `x->left` probably can not be `NULL` if left > right but the analogous code might hit the case where `x->right` is `NULL` if `left == right == 0`